# SQL Server 2014 SSIS and SSRS access

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssis

My company has a database located on a server. On that same server there is an installation of SQL Server. I plan on installing SQL Server on my workstation (we have the appropriate license) so I can access the data for reporting purposes. I will need access to SSRS and SSIS on my workstation to help with this process. Will this be issue for me? Will I be able to install SSRS and SSIS or will it only be accessible on the Server's installation of SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install SSRS and SSIS in your workstation and use the database in your company server as datasource.

Keep in mind your workstation must have access to your company network and your Windows credentials / Sql Server login should have the right permission level in order to connect to the SQL SERVER instance.

I assume you want to install SSIS to design some kind of ETL or data integration process. I'd recommend you only use your workstation to design/develop/test SSIS packages then deploy those packages to your server and run them from it.

The same recommendation if you want to use your workstation as a report server. If you need to delivery reporting services to a large number of users it is possible your machine cannot handle it.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer alejandro. I'm doing the installation next work week. I'll create a package using your suggestion and see how it turns out. I'll follow-up soon with the results.

Answer (score 1):

**My company has a database located on a server. On that same server there is an installation of SQL Server. I plan on installing SQL Server on my workstation (we have the appropriate license) so I can access the data for reporting purposes.**

No need to install SQL Server Database Server on your workstation to access the data for reporting. You just need to install SSRS and SSIS locally on your workstation if you plan to work on reports and create your ETL packages locally.

**I will need access to SSRS and SSIS on my workstation to help with this process. Will this be issue for me?**

If you are using a local account to run SSIS/SSRS on your workstation you may run into some permission issues, especially for windows pass-through authentication when accessing data sources - unless you plan to store static data source credentials. You could run the SSRS/SSIS as domain service accounts that have "Write Public Information" permissions to enable Kerberos Authentication, which eliminate the double-hop issues you may potentially face

As pointed out by alejandro you will also need to make sure these service accounts have appropriate permissions set on the remote SQL Server Database Instance

**Will I be able to install SSRS and SSIS or will it only be accessible on the Server's installation of SQL Server?**

You should be able to install SSRS/SSIS on your workstation, and it doesnt have to be installed on SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

Thanks again for your help. I have the necessary permission to the database and have already started building some queries via SQL Express.

The IT department is going to add a developer server with an installation of SQL Server. We will test the packages on this server and once we are satisfied with the results we will deploy them to the server that houses the databases. I'm assuming they will add the necessary permissions to do so, but we will see. I also installed SQL Express on my workstation and can at least test the TSQL queries on my workstation, and I believe SSRS, before hand.

As a side question:
If there are multiple installations of SQL Server on different workstations/servers, will the server that houses the database have master administrative rights versus the other installations. I ask because each time I install SQL Server I add the admin account, and to me it seems that each installation could have administrative rights. Is that right?